# How to minus data length inside the index of a list, if the index is an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, list

Well, first of all, I am not sure whether my title in this question delivered what I want to ask or not. I just do not sure how to describe my problem in one sentence, hopefully the title would not cause any misleading.

If I have a list. Inside the list contain 100 data : `list<100>`

If I put this list inside a 1 second timer tick and do like this:

```
myList.RemoveRange(0, 2);
```

This mean, every 1 second, the data length inside the list will be -2;

This mean, every 1 second, it will be `<98> , <96> , <94> .... <0>`

Now my problem is...I still have a list, but the list will contain an array: `list<array[100]>`

Now, what I want is, every 1 second, the data length inside the array inside the list will be -2. But I am not sure know how to do this...

what I want is, every 1 second `<array[98]> , <array[96]> , <array[96]> ... <array[0]>`

And so, if the list contain `<array0[100] , array1[100], array2[100]>`

if i put this list inside a loop, every 1 second, it should be

```
array0[98] , array0[96] ... array0[0]
array1[98] , array1[96] ... array1[0]
array2[98] , array2[96] ... array2[0]
```

**Update:**

```
List<int[]> myList = new List<int[]>();
object myLock = new object();
Random rand = new Random();

public Form1()
{
    timer1second.Start();
}

private void SomeMethod()
{
    int[] myData = new int [100]

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        //generate some random number to store inside myData[]
        myData[i] = rand.Next(1 , 10); 
    }

    lock (myLock)
    {
        myList.Add(myData); //mean List[0] = myData[100]
    }
}

private void timer1second_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     lock (myLock)
     {
         //do something here in myList to get the myData[100 - 2]
         //so that every 1 second tick, the data length inside the MyData will be -2              
     }
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 100; i > 0;i--){System.Threading.Threading.Sleep(1000);..do something here}`

Comment: this is just a -loop, what I need is how to do something like myList.RemoveRange(0, 2); inside a list where the list is inside a 1 second timer tick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Convert the `Array` item into a `List`.
2. Then remove the range from the List
3. Convert it back to an `Array`.
4. Insert it back into the `List`

Here is a sample:

```
        int currentIndex = 0;

        var myList = new List<int[]>();
        var intArray = new int[100];
        myList.Add(intArray);

        // Convert to List. 
        var newIntArrayList = myList[currentIndex].ToList();

        // Remove the ranges 
        // Index would be based on you logic
        newIntArrayList.RemoveRange(0, 2);

        //Replace the list with the new arry
        myList[currentIndex] = newIntArrayList.ToArray();
```

**Update :** [Array.Resize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx) should also help.

```
       int currentIndex = 0;
        int arrayLength = 100;

        var myList = new List<int[]>();
        var intArray = new int[100];
        myList.Add(intArray);

        // Get the array
        var array = myList[currentIndex];

        // Resize
        Array.Resize(ref array, arrayLength-2);

        //Replace the list with the update array
        myList[currentIndex] = array;
```

Comment: i am using this method now^^ is there any other way like array re sizing?

Comment: @jhyap: Updated with [Array.Resize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx) sample..

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
{
    myList.Add(i);
}

for (int i = 100; i > 0; i--)
{
    System.Threading.Threading.Sleep(1000);
    myList.RemoveAt(i);
    i -= 1;
    myList.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Comment: what if the List<int[]> myList = new List<int[]>() ?

Answer (score 0):

Resizing lists and arrays is an expensive operation. Would you consider a custom data structure for your needs with convinient interface and optimized underlying structure? So every tick you will only increment and integer value representing offset:

```
class Data
{
    const int Step = 2;

    List<int[]> data;
    List<int> cursors;

    public Data()
    {
        data = new List<int[]>();
    }

    public void AddArray(int[] array)
    {
        data.Add(array);
        cursors.Add(array.Length);
        // or cursors.Add(0), depending on your needs
    }

    public void Tick()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cursors.Count; i++)
        {
            cursors[i] -= Step;
            // or cursors[i] += Step, depending on your needs
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> GetValuesAtIndex(int index)
    {
        for (int i = 0, i < data[index].Length; i++)
        {
            if (i > cursors[index]) // or i < cursors[index]
            {
                yield return data[index][i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```